# GString Error - how to use URL parameter in program [Grails]

Tags: grails, configuration

I want to change the configuration by URL parameter and try like below.

In Controller

```
class TestController {
  def grailsApplication
  def changeConfig{
     Map testConfig = grailsApplication.config.test
     def accountConfig = testConfig.${params.account}
  }
}
```

in Config.groovy

```
test {
  'default' {
    debug     = false
    Key       = 'aaa'
  }
  'another' {
    debug     = true
    Key       = 'bbb'
  }
}
```

Then, I want to change the configuration by run the URL like below

```
http://localhost/myApp/test/changeConfig?account=another
```

but, this code makes error like below.

```
Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.$() is applicable for argument types:
```

How can I change the configuration by URL parameters?

Comment: You need to put ${} inside double quote "" in groovy class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it will work, but your line

```
def accountConfig = testConfig.${params.account}
```

Is wrong, it should be

```
def accountConfig = testConfig."${params.account}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat ConfigObject as a map. So you can do it like this too.

```
 Map testConfig = grailsApplication.config.test
 def accountConfig = testConfig[params.account]
```

Or

```
 def accountConfig = testConfig.get(params.account)
```